# PHP + HTML table: Fire appropriate MySql query from each cell of the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

*The title is not most suitable, but this is the best I could think of. Feel free to suggest EDIT.*

**Summary:**

I have come from Android development where I have used [`RecyclerView`](http://enoent.fr/images/articles/recyclerview-basics/recyclerview-grid-3-vertical.png) to show a grid of various items from the database. There I could use the `onClickListener()`and `Position`  to get which `RecyclerView` item *(first,second,third..)* is clicked by user and can proceed with actions.

**Set up:**

I am new to web development and by far I have managed to create an `HTML` table and I am firing appropriate query to get items from the database. I am then showing these data from database in each table cell. The data consists of image link (from a folder in same directory) and other text data about that image. My table looks something like this. [Click here](http://postimg.org/image/tts7z4psv/)

**Problem:**

I want to add an options like `Accept` in each cell of the table such that when user clicks on that, a query fires to set the Boolean `isAccepted` **for that item** in DB as true. I can manage the query part but I am facing problem how to set this up in my php script.

**What do I ecpect?**

That's absolutely OK if I dont get the ready made code. I want to be guided as what technology to be used and if possible a link to the guiding tutorial. I hope it can be done usng PHP and HTML only.

My php script:

```
<table id="customers">
<?php

$MAX_COLS = 5;

$query = "select * FROM `complaints`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    if($i % $MAX_COLS == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<img src='SCB2/Images/temp2.jpg' alt='Sample image' style='width:200px;height:200px;' >";
    echo "<br>"."Image ID: ".$row[0];
    echo "<br>"."Latitude: ".$row[2];
    echo "<br>"."Longitude: ".$row[3];
    echo "<br>"."Zip: ".$row[4];
    echo "<br>"."Done by: ".$row[8];
    echo "<td>";
    $i++;
    if($i % $MAX_COLS == 0){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: `</br>` is not valid HTML. It should be either `<br/>` or simply `<br>`. Also, why are you concatenating strings like that? You could just echo everything in one go: `"<br>Image ID: {$row[0]}";`

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Is this concatenation wrong by any means? I was following an online tutorial and did as directed to me.

Comment: </br> works in all browsers

Comment: @newUser There is nothing particularly "wrong" about it, but you don't need to concatenate lots of strings together like that when you can just treat it as one string.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'll definitely consider that. Any help regarding the main question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the link to the HTML that is outputted:

```
echo "<td>";
// ...
echo "<br><a href='/some/path/to/accept.php?imageid={$row[0]}'>Accept</a>";
echo "<td>";
```

And then in the accept file you can deal with it:

```
// /some/path/to/accept.php

// Get the image id from the query string
$imageid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'imageid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

try {
    // Create a database connection
    $db = new PDO(
        'mysql:dbname=databaseName;host=localhost',
        'username', 'pa55w0rd',
        array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
    );
    // Create a prepared statement and bind the image id to it
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE complaints SET isAccepted = 1 WHERE Id = :id');
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $imageid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // Execute the statement
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        die('SUCCESS!');
    } else {
        die($stmt->error);
    }
}
catch (\PDOException $e) {
    die('PDO Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

You should obviously do some checks that the user is allowed to accept the image.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. i'll try implementing this. Well, without refreshing the page, can I also add a field under each image where the text changes from `Not accepted` to `Accepted`?

Comment: You would have to write some Javascript to make it do that. I am sure there are plenty of questions about that on StackOverflow already. Use the search box on the top right.